# How to make a circle within another circle?

Tags: geometry, random

I'm coding a "storm" for a battle royale map, and I'm trying to make a new safe zone (a perfect circle) inside of a preexisting circle.

Right now, it looks like this:
[Link to circle picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rbl79.png)

This, as you can see, is a big bug in my code, which is:

```
cir = new Circle(random.nextInt(cir.Width-cir.X)+cir.X, random.nextInt(Math.abs(cir1.Height-cir.Y))+cir.Y, 270, 270, 135, Color.cyan, true);
```

`cir1` is a preexisting Circle I created, which I am changing the values of.
`cir` is the Circle I created before (e.g. for Safe Zone 3, `cir1` is the new Circle, and `cir` is Safe Zone 2.

My math to get the circles' $x$'s and $y$'s explained:
The math is: $rndInt(d-x)+x$ and $rndInt(|d-y|)+y$.
$d$ is the diameter of the circle, $x$ is the left x value, and $y$ is the top y of the circle.

This - in theory - should work, but it doesn't, as seen in the image.

In it, I basically get a random number between $0$ and the difference of the diameter and x.
From there, I add it to x. In theory, this will make a number and add it to x, making it between the preexisting circle.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? I've spent weeks trying to figure out a formula, and this is the best I've got.

Comment: Although this is a maths QA stack, if you could provide an MWE that might rule out any mathematical errors on your part... Otherwise, perhaps good old Stack Overflow might be your friend, too.

Comment: To get a point inside the circle, the relation is `x+rndInt(d)`,`y-rndInt(d)$`

Comment: I don't see why this should work even  "in theory." You have two different objects (`cir` and `cir1`) contributing parameters to your constructor. One of these presumably is not the "preexisting" circle you wanted to stay inside. Moreover, all you would have done (if it worked like you said) is to put one corner of the bounding box inside the other bounding box--almost all the rest could be outside.

Comment: By the way, there are multiple Java classes named Circle (or in one case Circle2D) documented online; so far yours is the only one I've seen that describes a circle by a corner of its bounding box, its width, and its height. (Can the width and height be different?) Everyone else uses the center and the radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not absolutely sure if I understood your problem statement correctly, so here is the question as I understood it:

> How do I ensure that a randomly generated circle is completely contained in an existing circle?

Let's assume the existing circle is centered at $(X, Y)$ and has radius $R = D/2$, where $D$ is its diameter.

First, pick a radius $r$, $0 \lt r \le R$ for the new circle.

Then, pick an uniform random angle $0\text{°} \le \varphi \lt 360\text{°}$, or $-180\text{°} \le \varphi \lt 180\text{°}$, or $0 \le \varphi \lt 2\pi$ in radians.

Finally, pick an uniform random deviation $d$ from center, $0 \le d \le R - r$.

The center of the new smaller circle is then
$$\bbox{ \left\lbrace \; \begin{aligned}
x &= X + d \cos \varphi \\
y &= Y + d \sin \varphi \\
\end{aligned} \right . }$$

The reason for using trigonometric functions instead of the [axis-aligned bounding box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis-aligned_bounding_box) is that you can fit a small circle completely within the bounding box of a larger circle, without overlapping at all with the larger circle.  Using the radius, and choosing the direction from the center of the larger circle randomly, avoids that sort of error completely.

In pseudocode (in no particular programming language), you could implement this using

```
Function RandomCircleInside(centerX, centerY, radius):
    Let  newRadius = radius * Random()
    Let  radians = 2.0 * 3.14159265358979323846 * Random()
    Let  deviation = (radius - newRadius) * Sqrt(Random())
    Let  newX = centerX + deviation * Cos(radians)
    Let  newY = centerY + deviation * Sin(radians)
    Return (newX, newY, newRadius)
End Function
```

where `Random()` is a function that returns an uniform random floating-point number between 0 and 1.0, inclusive (meaning it can return 0 and 1); and `Sin()` and `Cos()` are the respective trigonometric functions, with argument in radians; and `Sqrt()` is the square root operation.  The square root is needed to ensure an uniform distribution within the disc.

If you want, you can also supply the `newRadius` parameter to the function (and not calculate it from `radius * Random()`); the function will work as long as `newRadius` ≤ `radius`.

If you cannot use trigonometric functions, we can rewrite the function as

```
Function RandomCircleInside(centerX, centerY, radius):
    Let  newRadius = radius * Random()
    Let  deviation = (radius - newRadius) * Random()
    Let  dd = deviation * deviation

    Do:
         dX = deviation - 2 * deviation * Random()
         dY = deviation - 2 * deviation * Random()
    While (dX*dX + dY*dY > dd)

    Let  newX = centerX + dX
    Let  newY = centerY + dY
    Return (newX, newY, newRadius)
End Function
```

This is just as good as the trigonometric function using one, except that it calls `Random()` about 27% "extra times" on average. (This uses the "exclusion method" to generate a random point within a circular disc. It generates a random point within the axis-aligned square that contains the disc, but ignores any point outside the disc. Since the ratio of their areas is $4 / \pi \approx 1.27324$, the do-while loop iterates 1.27324 times on average. That is, most times it only does one iteration, and sometimes more than one.)

If your circles are determined by their axis-aligned bounding box, note that the left edge (minimum $x$) is at $X - R$; right edge (maximum $x$) at $X + R$; top edge (minimum $y$) is at $Y - R$; and bottom edge (maximum $y$) at $Y + R$.

If you define your circles based on their axis-aligned bounding box, then center X is `(right + left) / 2` = `left + width/2`, center Y is `(bottom + top) / 2` = `top + height/2`, and radius is `(right - left) / 2` = `(bottom - top) / 2` = `(right - left + bottom - top) / 4` = `width / 2` = `height / 2` = `(width + height) / 2`.

Comment: @DavidK: Good point. That radial distribution in an unit disc is obtained by taking the square root of the uniform distribution; now fixed. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that looks good. Either of these methods should be fine for what OP asked for.